# Possible to use more than one argument on __getitem__?

Tags: python

I am trying to use

```
__getitem__(self, x, y):
```

on my Matrix class, but it seems to me it doesn't work (I still don't know very well to use python).
I'm calling it like this:

```
print matrix[0,0]
```

Is it possible at all to use more than one argument? Thanks. Maybe I can use only one argument but pass it as a tuple?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`__getitem__` only accepts one argument (other than `self`), so you get passed a tuple.

You can do this:

```
class matrix:
    def __getitem__(self, pos):
        x,y = pos
        return "fetching %s, %s" % (x, y)

m = matrix()
print m[1,2]
```

outputs

```
fetching 1, 2
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) for `object.__getitem__` for more information.

Comment: Where does the documentation actually say that multiple arguments are converted to a tuple?

Answer (score 34):

Indeed, when you execute `bla[x,y]`, you're calling `type(bla).__getitem__(bla, (x, y))` -- Python automatically forms the tuple for you and passes it on to `__getitem__` as the second argument (the first one being its `self`).  There's no good way<sup>[1]</sup> to express that `__getitem__` wants more arguments, but also no need to.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> In Python `2.*` you can actually give `__getitem__` an auto-unpacking signature which will raise `ValueError` or `TypeError` when you're indexing with too many or too few indices...:

```
>>> class X(object):
...   def __getitem__(self, (x, y)): return x, y
... 
>>> x = X()
>>> x[23, 45]
(23, 45)
```

Whether that's "a good way" is moot... it's been deprecated in Python 3 so you can infer that Guido didn't consider it *good* upon long reflection;-).  Doing your own unpacking (of a single argument in the signature) is no big deal and lets you provide clearer errors (and uniform ones, rather than ones of different types for the very similar error of indexing such an instance with 1 vs, say, 3 indices;-).

Comment: My understanding about the deprecation of argument unpacking in 3.x was not so much that "Guido didn't consider it good", but more that hardly anyone knew the feature even existed in the language, and it significantly complicated the compiler.

Comment: @Laurence, yep -- complicated and very rarely used -> not good!-)

Comment: I regularly used it and it was quite nice, but the issue was that it complicated reflection. I'll mainly miss it for its use in lambda functions

Comment: I like this implementation. It gives you an idea of the format of the expected tuple. Rock On

Comment: I agree with @Casebash. I come from C#/.Net where secondary (tertiary, etc) parameters are allowed. Compiler complication is not necessarily a valid argument as it is essentially another way of saying, "pain in the neck to maintain." Feature awareness is about educating a user on what is available in the "toolbox" so to speak. Robust languages generally have some "pain in the neck" features and not every developer is going to know (or ever need to use) some features. So we should, by those arguments, reduce the language to what the average programmer knows and uses on a regular basis.

Answer (score 5):

No, `__getitem__` just takes one argument (in addition to `self`). In the case of `matrix[0, 0]`, the argument is the tuple `(0, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I learned today that you can pass double index to your object that implements **getitem**, as the following snippet illustrates:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [[1]]
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]
    
c = MyClass()
print(c[0][0])
```

I guess this is nothing fancy: the second `[0]` is merely accessing elements of the builtin `[1]`.

Comment: @oliver I didn't downvote, but my guess is because this implementation assumes the class nests an array, which is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call `__getitem__` instead of using brackets.

Example:

```py
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = [5, 7, 9]
    def __getitem__(self, i, plus_one=False):
        if plus_one:
            i += 1
        return self.a[I]

foo = Foo()
foo[0] # 5
foo.__getitem__(0) # 5
foo.__getitem__(0, True) # 7
```

Comment: That's true, but not very user-friendly.