# List of List Class

Tags: python, inheritance

I want to create my own List of Lists class. I want it to throw a list index out of range error when one of the indices are negative.

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index < 0:
            raise IndexError("list index out of range")
        return super(MyList, self).__getitem__(index)
```

Example:

```
x = MyList([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
x[-1][0]  # list index of of range -- Good
x[-1][-1] # list index out of range -- Good
x[0][-1]  # returns 3 -- Bad
```

How do I fix this? I've looked into possible solutions such as: [Possible to use more than one argument on __getitem__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685389/possible-to-use-more-than-one-argument-on-getitem). But I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The outer list is a list of your custom class. However, each inner list is a list of the standard `list` class. Use the custom class for each list and it should work.

For example:

```
x = MyList([MyList([1,2,3]), MyList([4,5,6]), MyList([7,8,9])])
```

Comment: When I do `x[0][0]`, I get the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: Using the class as it appears in your question, with `x` as it appears in my answer, accessing `x[0][0]` as it appears in your comment, I get `1`. Check your work for typos.

Comment: Ahhhhh, yeah it was a typo on my end. Thanks