# overloaded __getitem__ accepting another argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, overloading

I want to make the `__getitem__` of one class be the sum of it and the item at the same index of another list.

```
>>> class Test(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.extend([1, 2, 3])
    def __getitem__(self, index, other):
        return self[index] + other[index]
>>> t = Test()
>>> t2 = [4, 5, 6]
```

However, my two attempts have resulted in errors:

```
>>> t[5, t2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    t[5, t2]
TypeError: __getitem__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'
>>> t.__getitem__(5, t2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    t.__getitem__(5, t2)
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 5, in __getitem__
    return self[index] + other[index]
TypeError: __getitem__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'
```

Is it possible to give `__getitem__` multiple arguments? If so, how? If not, is there a way to emulate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible because you get a tuple of "indices" in `__getitem__` not multiple parameters:

```
class Test(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.extend([1, 2, 3])

    def __getitem__(self, value):
        # this makes sure that a sequence with exactly 2 elements is passed in: (thanks @ShadowRanger)
        index, other = value  
        return super().__getitem__(index) + other[index]

>>> t = Test()
>>> t2 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> t[2, t2]
9   # 3 + 6
>>> t[1, t2]
7   # 2 + 5
>>> t[0, t2]
5   # 1 + 4
```

There are some caveats however:

- You need to explicitly call `super().__getitem__` so you don't end up in an recursion.
- You have to pay attention to the number of arguments passed to your `__getitem__` if you want to allow normal slicing.
- This behaviour will confuse users, so I wouldn't actually recommend using it!

Comment: To ensure you don't get more arguments than expected, I'd skip explicit indexing and just use sequence unpacking: `index, other = value`. It's faster too (Python is optimized for cheap `tuple` packing and unpacking, less so for indexing). I agree this is... odd... to say the least, and I'd recommend against it due to risk of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to give **getitem** multiple arguments? If so, how? If not, is there a way to emulate it?

Why would want to emulate this? You're missing the point of "magic methods". Python provides you with these methods to give a form of operator overloading. Here is an excerpt from the Python documentation section *3.3. Special method names*, that describes what "magic methods" are meant to be used for:

> A class can implement certain operations that are invoked by special syntax (such as arithmetic operations or subscripting and slicing) by defining methods with special names. **This is Python’s approach to operator overloading, allowing classes to define their own behavior with respect to language operators**.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Furthermore, this makes your class ambiguous to readers of your code who are expected `__getitem__` to return a single element.

Since @MSeifert has already given you a way to achieve the behavior you want, I won't post my solution. But I strongly encourage you to create your own custom method. If you still do choose to make changes to the functionality of your `__getitem__` method, I highly recommend that you at least document these changes and make it clear that your implementation of `__getiem__` has different behavior than the normal implementation.

Comment: I was inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685389/possible-to-use-more-than-one-argument-on-getitem/1685412) to answer your first paragraph: `matrix[i, j]` or `matrix[x, y, z]` are good reasons to emulate this. It reads much more nicely than `matrix.get_item(x, y, z)`.

Comment: @Guimoute I completely agree haha. I wrote this question almost five years ago, when I was still a pretty new programmer and hardly had an experience with libraries like `numpy` which make use of multiple arguments to `__getitem__`. Long story short, this answer shows my naivety pretty well! Now, I still wouldn't recommend what the OP is doing though, since he's passing in a list!