# Formal syntax of Python's extended slice notation?

Tags: python, syntax, slice

Numpy, for example, allows multi-dimensional slices:

```
a[:, 0, 7:9]
```

This raises the question: what else is possible? (Imagine the possibilities!)

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1685450/1143274) and some experimentation (see below), if there is a comma, Python builds a tuple of objects, some of which may be slice objects, and passes it (as `key`) to `__getitem__(self, key)` of `a`.

The [documentation for `__getitem__(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) doesn't specify this behaviour. Is there any official documentation that I missed? In particular, how backwards-compatible is this syntax? (Searching the web for "python extended slice notation" gives ["What's new in Python 2.3"](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html), which doesn't mention it.)

---

### Experimentation

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     def __getitem__(self, x):
...         print repr(x)


>>> t = Test()
```

First, things that Python finds recognisable for multi-slicing:

```
>>> t[1]
1

>>> t['a':,]
(slice('a', None, None),)

>>> t['a':7:('b','c'),]
(slice('a', 7, ('b', 'c')),)

# Seems like it can be arbitrary objects?
>>> t[(t,t):[4,5]]
slice((<__main__.Test object at 0x07D04950>, <__main__.Test object at 0x07D04950>), [4, 5], None)

>>> t[::]
slice(None, None, None)

>>> t[:]
slice(None, None, None)

>>> t[::,1,::,::,:,:,:]
(slice(None, None, None), 1, slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None),  slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None))

>>> t[...]
Ellipsis

>>> t[... , ...]
(Ellipsis, Ellipsis)

>>> t[  .   .      .    ]
Ellipsis
```

Some things that are NOT allowed (SyntaxError):

```
# Semicolon delimiter
t['a':5; 'b':7:-7]
# Slice within a slice
t['a':7:(9:5),]
# Two trailing commas
t[5,,]
# Isolated comma
t[,]
# Leading comma
t[,5]
# Empty string
t[]
# Triple colon
t[:::]
# Ellipses as part of a slice
t[1:...]
t[1:2:...]
# Ellipses inside no-op parens:
t[(...)]
# Any non-zero and non-three number of dots:
t[.]
t[..]
t[ .  .  .  . ]
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using that allows `t['a':7:('b','c'),]` to work? That's a bug, I tested Python 2.4 and up and they all reject the lower bound and stride by raising a `TypeError` exception. Same for `t[(t,t):[4,5]]`.  I no longer have a Python 2.3 build.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)`, I think that's a standard install from the official Python website. (Also, just checked that it also behaves that way when used directly in the terminal — it does.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Anything* is possible, as long as it is a valid Python expression. The object produced by the expression between `[...]` is passed to the `__getitem__` method. That's it.

Commas produce a tuple, `:` colons in an expression produce a `slice()` object. Beyond that, use whatever you want.

That's because the grammar allows for *any `expression_list`* in the notation. See the [reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions):

> ```
> subscription ::=  primary "[" expression_list "]"
> ```

Slicing is further specified in the [*Slicings* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings):

> ```
> slicing      ::=  primary "[" slice_list "]"
> slice_list   ::=  slice_item ("," slice_item)* [","]
> slice_item   ::=  expression | proper_slice
> proper_slice ::=  [lower_bound] ":" [upper_bound] [ ":" [stride] ]
> lower_bound  ::=  expression
> upper_bound  ::=  expression
> stride       ::=  expression
> ```

So again arbitrary `expression`s are allowed, and `:` triggers the `proper_slice` grammar rule.

Note that the `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` and `stride` expression results are used to construct a `slice()` object, which can only handle *integer values*. Anything that can't be converted to an integer will result in a `TypeError` being raised. That's not the same thing as a syntax error; `t[1:...]` is syntactically just fine, but `...` is not convertable to an integer so you get a runtime `TypeError` exception. Your two examples using non-integer slice values are not possible on Python versions 2.4 and up at the very least.

Your actual syntax errors all stem from invalid expressions. Apart from the `:` `proper_slice` notation, if you can't put the part between `[...]` on the right-hand side of an assignment, you can't use it in a slice either.

For example, `;` can only be used to put multiple [simple statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html) on a single logical line. Statements can contain expressions, but expressions can never contain statements, excluding `;` from expressions. `(9:5),` is not a valid expression (nowhere else in Python could you use a `:` in parentheses, the [`parenth_form` rule](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms) doesn't allow for any such options).

The [Python 2 grammar for slicings](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#slicings) is a little more elaborate in that `...` is a specific notation in the grammar there, and you can't actually use the `...` outside of slicings (in Python 3 you can use `...` anywhere an expression is valid), which is why `t[(...)]` is a syntax error in Python 2 but not in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the earlier answer. If you define

```py
class Foo:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return key
```

and do `Foo()[0, :, 1:2, 1:2:3]` it will give you the internal representation which is:

```
>>> Foo()[0, :, 1:2, 1:2:3]
(0, slice(None, None, None), slice(1, 2, None), slice(1, 2, 3))
```